# ANTLR from the command line with Java: Which jar and where do i get it?

Tags: java, antlr

I want to run an ANTLR jar from the command line to run a parser, as described at the bottom of http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=729, where it says,

> What if I want to test my parser without generating code? Easy. Just
>   run ANTLR in interpreter mode. It can't execute your actions, but it
>   can create a parse tree from your input to show you how it would be
>   matched. Use the org.antlr.tool.Interp main class. In the following, I
>   interpret simplec.g on t.c, which contains "int x;"

and follows that with

> $ java org.antlr.tool.Interp simplec.g WS program t.c

Which jar do I download, and where can i get it? I tried antlr-3.4-complete.jar, but the output suggests that that may be only the parser generator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Which jar do I download

The sentence following the command says this:

> *"In above command, we are considering ANTLR3 jar lies in your classpath."*

where ANTLR3 jar presumably means the antlr-3.1.2.jar file mentioned earlier in the page.

> ... and where can i get it?

The ANTLR FAQ answers this one:

- ["Where do I find this damn thing"](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=734)

Answer (score 0):

I just started using ANTLR and found developing in it and java was quick and straightforward in Eclipse with the ANTLR IDE plug-in. This will give you an idea of what that process is like:  [Testing ANTLR Grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838068/testing-antlr-grammar/10886842#10886842).